# GetFiles/GetDirectories and EnumerateDirectories/EnumerateFiles Performance penalty on UNC/virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, directory

I have a File Server which is mapped to a network drive letter W. it has 732 main folders and sub folders and a lot of files. I have mapped a virtual Directory to this drive and named it "Documents".

Now I want to check how much time it takes to find only the folders which contains "final" in it. i created a Console app not a web app yet and write below code which gave me results very very slow which is not desired. Please find below the code

```
DateTime startdatetime = DateTime.Now;
var dirs = from dir in
Directory.EnumerateDirectories("W:\\", "*Final*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
select dir;
foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = EndDate - startdatetime;
Console.WriteLine(t.Minutes);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This gave me only folders not file names in 5 minutes on first run and 6 minutes on second.
Old code which i used to get only folders was

```
DateTime startdatetime = DateTime.Now;
string[] dirs = 
    Directory.GetDirectories("W:\\", "*Final*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = EndDate - startdatetime;
Console.WriteLine(t.Minutes);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The above code gave me list of folders in 6-7 minutes.
Combined Files and Folders above code gave results in 12 minutes. That is huge performance penalty on web.

Any idea guys how to reduce this penalty cap? I am stuck here.

Comment: How many results are there? How long does it take, if you remove `Console.WriteLine(dir);`?

Comment: How often does the drive change? Why not take the first penalty, then create a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) on that drive so you don't have to constantly research through everything?

Comment: how many results are there?
around 10 only for folders.

How long does it take, if you remove Console.WriteLine(dir);?
For Directory.etDirectories same 6 minutes and for Enumerable one 0 (because enumerable only works when accessed)

How often drive change?
Almost every day. I will look at the FileSystemWatcher

What is my goal?
My goal is to give a textbox of search and user enters any name and i search the folder and files and list them down in http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/

Comment: You should make a service to dump the data into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel iterating entire directory and files is very costly. Try to find out why you need that. Why not to get one directory and search files inside it. I mean try to do some analysis with your tech team and business owners so that every one is realistic.

The only thing that I can think of is using Parallel for each loop rather than the normal one so that you can utilize your CPU's. But it will reduce the cost but not drastically.

Comment: Parallel loop? i have not heard it before...hmmm
is it the case I am using mapped network drive that is why this is slow?

Comment: Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx. It will give you more information about ||rl foreach. Even you will get answer to your original question.

Comment: I tried parallel for each but no vain. performance was same. I think the latency of network drive is impossible to cover.

Comment: Try to talk to your business people first, why they want to do this costly operation. Reading on directory on a map network drive is very costly, and here you are trying to read directories + Files. Probably you seek some suggestion from your business as well.

Comment: Shailesh thank you for your response. i think it is safe just to tell them that this is not possible. I hope they understand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe their request is not strange at all,they just want a search on their asset. you can have a small DB while it is synchronized with your document folder and its files paths and your query result could be on the table instead of being on the IO files.